download button slower with nginx in nextjs 15
I have a route.ts file under api folder like this:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { conditionalEvergreenDownloadQuery } from "@/app/lib/data";
import { Readable } from "stream";
import { createReadStream } from "fs";

type ReportHeaders = Array<
  keyof Awaited<ReturnType<typeof conditionalEvergreenDownloadQuery>>[number]
>;

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const searchParams = request.nextUrl.searchParams;

  // Check if search params are defined
  const hasSearchParams = Array.from(searchParams.entries()).length > 0;

  try {
    let dataStream: Readable;

    if (hasSearchParams) {
      // Use existing query params logic
      const queryParams = {
        it_service: searchParams.get("service") || undefined,
        it_org_6: searchParams.get("org_6") || undefined,
        it_org_7: searchParams.get("org_7") || undefined,
        it_org_8: searchParams.get("org_8") || undefined,
        software_product_version_name:
          searchParams.get("software_product_version_name") || undefined,
        service_owner: searchParams.get("service_owner") || undefined,
        eg_status: searchParams.get("eg_status") || undefined,
        eim_scope:
          searchParams.get("eim_scope") === null
            ? undefined
            : searchParams.get("eim_scope") === "true",
      };

      const data = await conditionalEvergreenDownloadQuery(queryParams);

      // Get headers that are inferred from the underlying query
      const headers = Object.keys(data[0]) as ReportHeaders;

      // Create a readable stream from the data
      dataStream = Readable.from(generateCSV(data, headers));
    } else {
      // If no search params, read from disk
      dataStream = createReadStream(process.env.FULL_REPORT || "");
    }

    // Set up the response
    const response = new NextResponse(dataStream as any);
    response.headers.set("Content-Type", "text/csv");
    response.headers.set(
      "Content-Disposition",
      `attachment; filename=evergreen_inventory_${new Date().toISOString()}.csv`
    );

    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: `Failed to generate csv with error: ${error}` },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}

async function* generateCSV(
  data: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof conditionalEvergreenDownloadQuery>>,
  headers: Array<
    keyof Awaited<ReturnType<typeof conditionalEvergreenDownloadQuery>>[number]
  >
) {
  // Yield the header row
  yield headers.join(",") + "\n";

  // Yield each data row
  for (const record of data) {
    const row = headers.map((header) => {
      const value = record[header];
      return escapeCsvValue(value);
    });
    yield row.join(",") + "\n";
  }
}

function escapeCsvValue(value: any): string {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) {
    return "";
  }
  const stringValue = String(value);
  if (
    stringValue.includes('"') ||
    stringValue.includes(",") ||
    stringValue.includes("\n")
  ) {
    return `"${stringValue.replace(/"/g, '""')}"`;
  }
  return stringValue;
}

and the download button.tsx is ca clinet component that calls that api route:
"use client";

import { toast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";
import { Download } from "lucide-react";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";

export function DownloadCSVButton() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const [isDownloading, setIsDownloading] = useState(false);

  const handleDownload = async () => {
    setIsDownloading(true);
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
    params.delete("page");

    const downloadUrl = `/dashboard/inventory/api/?${params.toString()}`;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(downloadUrl);
      if (!response.ok) throw new Error("Download Failed");

      const reader = response.body?.getReader();
      const filename =
        response.headers.get("Content-Disposition")?.split("filename=")[1] ||
        "evergreen_inventory.csv";

      if (!reader) throw new Error("Unable to read response");

      const chunks = [];
      while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();
        if (done) break;
        chunks.push(value);
      }

      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "text/csv" });
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.download = filename;
      link.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

      toast({
        title: "Success",
        description: "Report has been generated",
        duration: 5000,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        title: `Error: ${error}`,
        description: "Failed to download CSV file, Please try again",
        variant: "destructive",
        duration: 5000,
      });
    } finally {
      setIsDownloading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <button
      className="flex h-9 items-center rounded-lg bg-blue-600 from-blue-300 to-blue-950 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white transition-colors hover:bg-gradient-to-r focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-blue-600"
      disabled={isDownloading}
      aria-label={isDownloading ? "Downloading ...." : "Export"}
      onClick={handleDownload}
    >
      <span>{isDownloading ? "Downloading ...." : "Export"}</span>
      <Download className="ml-2 h-4 w-4"></Download>
    </button>
  );
}

I noticed the downloads if I access the server directly, that is not behind the reverse proxy of nginx are considerably faster than behind the proxy. Why is that ? how can i improve this ?
